# What is PMMCOREV in msp430?

Tags: msp430

I am studing WSN and in MSP430 CPU from Texas Instruments, i faced PMMCOREV. I tryed to find out what this is but i could not found something. Can anyone tell me what does it stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 2.2.1 of the User's Guide says:

> Higher MCLK speeds require higher levels of V<sub>CORE</sub>. Higher levels of V<sub>CORE</sub> consume more power, and so
>   the core voltage has been made programmable in up to four steps to allow it to provide only as much
>   power as is required for a given MCLK setting. The level is controlled by the PMMCOREV bits.